# How do I reshape my dataframe by ID, whilst creating new columns for variables based on their value?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a survey dataset that has individual rows for each question answered by each participants. So the dataset looks like this:

| ID | Name | Question | Answer | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Favourite colour? | Red | USA |
| 1 | John | Favourite food? | Burgers | USA |
| 1 | John | Favourite film? | Moana | USA |
| 2 | Jane | Favourite colour? | Blue | UK |
| 2 | Jane | Favourite food? | Chips | UK |
| 2 | Jane | Favourite film? | Toy Story | UK |

I want to reshape it by the ID column, creating new columns for each unique Question variable, and retain the Answer and Location responses, so it looks like this...

| ID | Name | Favourite colour? | Favourite food? | Favourite film? | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Red | Burgers | Moana | USA |
| 2 | Jane | Blue | Chips | Toy Story | UK |

Really appreciate any help and support!!!

**Updated progress**

After @Phil comments I tried:

```
pivot_wider(df, names_from = Question, values_from = Answer)
```

But I got the warning:

> Warning message:
>
> Values from `Answer` are not uniquely identified;
> output will contain list-cols. • Use `values_fn = list` to suppress
> this warning. • Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise
> duplicates. • Use the following dplyr code to identify duplicates.
> {data} |>   dplyr::summarise(n = dplyr::n(), .by = c(Number, Name,
> Location, Question))   |>   dplyr::filter(n > 1L)

@r2evans would welcome your help!!!

**Previous edits**
I have tried using the pivot_wider function but it keeps saying no column exists:

```
df2 <- pivot_wider(df1, 
             timevar = "Question",
             times = c("Favourite colour?",
                       "Favourite food?",
                       "Favourite film?",
             idvar = c("ID", "Name", "Location", 
             direction = "wide")
```

I also tried:

A)

```
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("ID", "Name","Location")
              , names_from = "Question"
              , values_from = "Answer")
```

which gave me a warning message:

```
Warning message:
Values from `Original.string.value` are not uniquely identified; output will contain
list-cols.
• Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
• Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates.
• Use the following dplyr code to identify duplicates.
  {data} |>
  dplyr::summarise(n = dplyr::n(), .by = c(Number, Name, Vendor, Confirmed.Risk.Tier,
  Question)) |>
  dplyr::filter(n > 1L)
```

And B)

```
pivot_wider(df,
            id_cols = c("ID", "Name", "Location"),
            names_from = "Question",
            values_from = "Answer", values_fn = list)
```

which ran without errors, but didn't seem to change my data frame at all

Comment: `pivot_wider(df1, names_from = Question, values_from = Answer)`

Comment: Where did you read to try those arguments (timevar, idvar, ...) for `pivot_wider`? They look like the arguments for `stats::reshape`.

Comment: if Phil's code and the dupe-links don't work for you, please [edit] your question to explain what is incorrect about them (likely in a [code block]), then @-ping me and we'll sort out the issues. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments and help. I have edited the question to explain what isn't working. In reality, I have hundreds of different values for the Question and Answer variables - could that have something to do with why it's not working? - @r2evans

Comment: Your data does not evoke that problem. It's generally up to you to make the question  _reproducible_. The error is clear, though, you have repeats in your `Answer`. Try `pivot_wider(quux, id_cols = c(ID, Name), names_from = Question, values_from = Answer)`. If that doesn't work, then you need to update your data to something that reflects your problem.